# trim leading forward slash and .php off file name

Tags: php, breadcrumbs, strpos

The code below gives me the file name of the page I'm on e.g. '/index.php' I want to know how I can trim this to be just index without the / and the .php.

```
$pageName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo $pageName;
```

I'm using this to output the location of where I am for a simple site breadcrumb.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) (requires php 5.2+):

```
$pageName = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo pathinfo($pageName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Alternatively, for a less flexible solution, use php's string functions and [`basename`](http://php.net/basename):

```
echo substr(basename($pageName), 0, -strlen('.php'));
```